# Return 'dir' command results into array/list

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, cmd.exe, array

I want to know how to return the output of the `dir` command into an array.
I'm using the command like this: `dir /s /b *.txt` how would I put each result (file name) into an array/list.
Thanks

Comment: I don't think plain batch files have any concept of arrays at all. Do you mean that you want to to do this in a PowerShell script?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling It can be simulated in a batch file [Arrays, linked lists and other data structures in cmd.exe (batch) script](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10167990)

Comment: [so] duplicate [Arrays, linked lists and other data structures in cmd.exe (batch) script](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10166386)